# Check values of an iddata in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, series

Good morning,

I want to ask you about an iddata object in Matlab. I want to know how it is possible to check its values (the y1 output). This is my code:

```
 data = iddata(M4,M4,0.01);
 sys = arx(data,[4 1 1])
 K=6;
 hf2=forecast(sys,data,K);
```

And I want to know the values of the forecast output, the 'hf2' (but it is an iddata object and I don't know how to do it). I have seen that I can plot it but I don't know how to know the values.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `properties` allows you to displays the names of properties of a matlab object. Then you can access the propertie's value with the command: `object.properties`.

For example: `hf2.OutputData`

Also read the doc about the object `iddata`, all the properties are explained.